# how can i add exception handling in c# i am trying to add only number should be accepted and divide by zero

Tags: c#, exception

i am having error when i add exception to only number should be excepted it says not in context

```
var num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtNumber1.Text);
var num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtNumber2.Text);
```

i tried adding exception to divide by 0 but its not working its outputting 0 instead of error message

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtNumber1.Text);
            var num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtNumber2.Text);

            var optrMenu = this.optrMenu.SelectedValue;

            var result = 0m;

            if (optrMenu == "+")
            {
                result = num1 + num2;
            }

            else if (optrMenu == "-")
            {
                result = num1 - num2;
            }

            else if (optrMenu == "*")
            {
                result = num1 * num2;
            }

            else if (optrMenu == "/")
            {
             result = num1 / num2;

            }
            lblresult.Text = result.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why did you set result=0m;

Comment: Where is try catch?

Comment: where is the code for the exception

Answer (score 1):

Use [Decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to ensure only proper numbers are considered for your calculation.

```
        var strVal1 = "1";
        var strVal2 = "2";

        var numVal1 = 0.0;
        var numVal2 = 0.0;

        if (!Decimal.TryParse(strVal1, out numVal1)
            numVal1 = 0;

        if (!Decimal.TryParse(strVal2, out numVal2)
            numVal2 = 0;
```

And as @lighting in his answer pointed out, use appropriate [Exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/index)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
else if (optrMenu == "/")
{
    try {
        result = num1 / num2;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException) {
       lblresult.Text = "Error! Divisor cannot be zero";
    }
}
```

Comment: lblresult is not changin the text

Comment: lblresult is not changing text for only the division, or the other operations too?

Comment: Only for divided by zero because I used decimal instead of int thank you